# Find the vector perpendicular to the curve $f(x, y) = x^2y+y^3$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, vectors

**Question:** Which given vector is perpendicular to the following curve at the point (1, 2).$$f(x, y) = x^2y+y^3 = 10$$

Given vectors: $<4, 3>, <-13, 4>, <2, 17>$ or non of these choices are correct.

**My attempt:** By taking the partial derivatives of this function, I was able to find that the gradient of the function to be $(4, 13)$. I was then able to find the tangent line of the function at the given point to be: $$x = \frac{{13(y-2)}}{4}+1$$
However, I'm not sure what to do next on out from here to evaluate the vector. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a vector $(a,b)$, an orthogonal vector is just $(-b,a)$, since $(a,b)·(-b,a)=-ab+ab=0$ (remember two vectors are orthogonal if and only if their dot product is zero). Since your gradient is $(4,13)$, which option do you think is the answer?

Comment: No, you were right on your first comment. The vector $(4,13)$ is not orthogonal to the tangent line, it's tangent, since it is precisely the vector of the direction of the tangent line. Orthogonal or perpendicular means forming a right angle.